# How long is the delay between retries of EventBus.RetryableException?

Tags: platform-event

In Platform Events, if you throw `EventBus.RetryableException`, [the doc states](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_apex_refire.htm):

> Events are resent after a small delay. The delay increases in
>   subsequent retries.

So, how small is small and how large is "increases"?

Answer (score 5):

So, I ran a controlled test -- your mileage may vary.

Controlled test was 100 Platform Events submitted in a single statement

```
EventBus.publish(myEvents);
```

The consuming Apex trigger coerced a DML exception that was in turn interpreted as a "transient" exception and the Apex trigger code threw `EventBus.RetryableException`.  No other activity was occurring on the org; no other events were published.

**(100 Events) Results** (# secs between each retry)

```
Retry 1: 15s
Retry 2: 32s
Retry 3: 27s
Retry 4: 31s
Retry 5: 29s
Retry 6: 61s
Retry 7: 60s
Retry 8: 59s
Retry 9: 61s
```

I repeated the experiment with a single event (rather than 100)

**(1 event) Results** (#secs between each retry)

```
Retry 1: 28s
Retry 2: 30s
Retry 3: 30s
Retry 4: 29s
Retry 5: 31s
Retry 6: 60s
Retry 7: 60s
Retry 8: 60s
Retry 9: 60s
```

So, based on these small test sets, I would say, that as of V44, the first 5 retries are spaced ~30s apart and the next 4 retries are spaced 60s apart. (*Don't go past **nine** retries as otherwise your trigger will be marked in error and no new events can be consumed*)

The EventBus.RetryableException exception is super useful in dealing with DmlException `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` and Query Exception `Record Not Available`

Note that it is not a panacea. Consider this:

First transaction includes events 1-10 and encounters a transient exception. Trigger throws EventBus.RetryableException

When the retry occurs, there might now be events 1-30 available to the transaction. Even if the record lock issue affecting events 1-10 has cleared, if a new record lock issue affects events 11-30 and the transaction throws EventBus.RetryableException again, events 1-10 are swept up as innocent bystanders and thrown into the replay queue along with events 11-30.  And so on.

Comment: +1 Nifty, although if not documented, I'm not sure you should rely on this being true for future releases/server load/etc, although it's nice to even have an estimate of any sort.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- hence the `your mileage may vary` -- i'm not relying on this, believe me. I was functional testing this feature and was curious